# CSS : Inheritance is not working as exected in subclasses

Tags: css, css-float

I have a CSS class, "MyParent", which is inherited by multiple sub classes. I want some of the properties of the "MyParent" class to be overridden by the sub classes, and these overrides should not affect the other subclasses.
Please see the example below.

CSS:

```
.MyParent {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
.MyChild1 .MyParent{
   background-color: blue !important;
   color: white !important;
}

.MyChild2 .MyParent{
  background-color: yellow !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="MyParent">
 this is parent div
</div>

<div class="MyChild1">
 this is child1
</div>

<div class="MyChild2">
 this is child2
</div>
```

I expect the MyParent div to be displayed with a yellow background and font color red. This works fine, but the other divs are not working as expected, despite that they override these properties.
I then tried the following:

```
.MyChild1, .MyParent{
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white !important;
 }

.MyChild2, .MyParent{
   background-color: green !important;
   color: white !important;
}
```

Now it's working partially, but the property being overridden in class "MyChild2" is affecting the parent class's property. Because of this, the div of class "MyParent" is not being rendered as expected. Most other children of the class are also affected. For this to work as expected, I could write one more sub class, but writing a sub class every time is annoying. Also, **some of the properties, like `bordercolor`, are not being inherited correctly**. Why am I seeing this behavior with CSS, and how can it be corrected?

Thanks in advance,
Saran.

Answer (score 2):

CSS properties are only inherited from parent elements if their value is set to `inherit`.

Many properties, such as `color`, have `inherit` as the default value, so they will inherit without any further action.

Most layout properties, including borders, have different default values (usually `0`), so they will not inherit from parent elements unless you manually set them to `inherit`.  After all, if you add a border to an element, you don't want every element inside of it to get a similar border...

To see what the default value for any given property is, check MDN.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Some properties are inherited and some aren't. The initial value of the inherited ones is not `inherit`, but they inherit when the cascade doesn't result in a value. Both inherited and non-inherited can be forced to inherit with `inherit`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inheriting

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, you can't make rule sets inherit styles from other ones.

[Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inheriting) can only happen from parents to children:

> **Inheritance** propagates property values from parent elements to their children. The **inherited value** of a property on an element is
>   the [computed value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#computed-value) of the property on the element’s parent
>   element.

Instead, I think you are interested in [cascading](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascading):

> The **cascade** takes a unordered list of [declared values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#declared-value) for a
>   given property on a given element, sorts them by their declaration’s
>   precedence as determined below, and outputs a single [cascaded
>   value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascaded-value).

```css
.MyParent, .MyChild1, .MyChild2 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
.MyChild1 {
   background-color: blue;
   color: white;
}
.MyChild2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyParent">
 this is parent div
</div>
<div class="MyChild1">
 this is child1
</div>
<div class="MyChild2">
 this is child2
</div>
```